How can this particular shape of shampoo bottle be created?
I wanted to create this extrude on this cylinder that I have modelled to look like the bottle from this shampoo. I am having problems with achieving this shape on the bottle, any help is appreciated!
The blue arrow is the extruded kind of look I want to apply on the model replica of the exact shampoo bottle




You could create your bottle and a circle that you put in front:

Use the Knife Project tool to cut the shape of the circle on the bottle (switch the bottle to Edit mode, CtrlLMB to select the circle, then go into the Mesh panel):

Mirror the shape on Y and Z, cut some horizontal edge loops with the knife:

Extrude the circular shape:

Bevel the edges:

Give it a Subdivision Surface modifier:


Thank you! I was able to recreate the shape
